# Looking for Java Multithreaded Client-Server chat application with database tutorial

Tags: java, mysql, database, multithreading, client-server

Im trying to build a Java Multithreaded Client-Server chat application with a database. The database is to store username and password. I am able to build a basic Java Multithreaded Client-Server chat application, but have no idea how to create the database side. Ive found lots of downloadable source code but I'm looking for a tutorial so I can learn what to do. Ive become lost in all the return results from google as I cant seem to find a tutorial for exactly what I want, it's possible I have come across one I need, but honestly I'm not 100% sure where to go. Just want to see if anyone knows a tutorial that covers this specific project. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it is for learning purposes, you probably do not want to build everything from scratch. And you will more likely find tutorials separated for client and for server.

- Have a look at the client side - [Smack XMPP](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/).
- Have a look at the server side - [Openfire](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/).

The nice thing about [XMPP](https://xmpp.org/) is you can swap client implementations and you can swap server implementations or connect them all to the same network, similar like email.

Comment: Yes trying to build from scratch and stuck on the database side of things. Thanks for your reply will check these out.